# iText Get number of characters in a field

Tags: java, itext

I am trying to find out which formats a date of birth should be in a empty field in a PDF using iText,

I can stamp the field with a value but then need to know what the date of birth must be.

I figured that if I get out the length of the field so I know how the format should be, because the formats can be:

YYYYMMDDNNNN (14 digits)

YYYYMMDD (10 digits)

YYMMDD (8 digits)

The field has a fixed number of digits, if I stamp the field with too many numbers, then the numbers that fall outside the field disappears.

**How do I find the length of the empty field?**

how i stamp the field:

```
private void stampValuesOnFields()
{
  try
  {
    PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(System.getProperty("com.sun.aas.instanceRoot") + "/PDF/Templates/org.pdf");
    String path = System.getProperty("com.sun.aas.instanceRoot") + "/PDF/Generated PDF/" + "new.pdf";
    PdfStamper stamper = new PdfStamper(reader, new FileOutputStream(path));

    stamper.getAcroFields().setField("field", "19321029");
  }catch(Exception e)
  {}
}
```

Here are pdfs I try to fill in, but I want it to work for other pdf files with other formats of Birthday:

http://www.korkortsportalen.se/upload/dokument/blanketter/foretag/tstrk1031_lakarintyg_diabetes.pdf
( the field under "Sökandens personnummer" )

Comment: There are different ways one can limit the number of characters added to a field. The most common way is to define the rectangle in such a way that it only accommodates for a limited number of characters without defining that number. A word such as "itinerary" takes less space than "monuments". Both have 9 characters, but the m's and the n's take more space than the i's and the r's. Show us your PDF and we can give a more conclusive answer to your question. Right now, the question is unanswerable.

Comment: Of course, if you want to make sure that the text fits the text field. You can always change the font size to `0`. When you add text to a text field with font size `0`, the font will adapt in order to make sure that the text fits. For instance: when you add "19321029" the actual font size could be 10, but when you add "321029" the actual font size could be 12.

Comment: I have added the pdf in my question. The problem is that I want it to work with pdf files with other formats of Birthday

Comment: Is `Intygsdatum` the birth date? Also: the person who created this form has named all fields in a similar way: starting with `Falt_`. That's annoying for people who want to know which field corresponds with which data.

Comment: no it is the field under "Sökandens personnummer", it's a Swedish authority that created the pdf so it's nothing I can do about it unfortunately :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're in luck. Your field defines a `/MaxLen` which means that you can find out the maximum length of the field. In the following screen shot, you can see the properties of the field / annotation dictionary for field `Falt__41` (which can be used to add the *Sökandens personnummer*):

[image]

As you can see, this field can contain a maximum of 12 characters. Moreover, the `/Ff` (fields flags) value is 29360128 or binary value: 1110000000000000000000000. This means that the following flags are active: **do not spell check**, **do not scroll**, and **comb**. The **comb** flag makes that whatever you enter, the characters will be evenly distributed over the available width. In this case, every character will take 1/12 of the available width.

Now how do you retrieve the `/MaxLen` value? That's more or less explained in my book, but I'm writing the following lines from memory:

```
AcroFields form = reader.getAcroFields();
AcroFields.Item item = form.getFieldItem("Falt__41");
PdfDictionary field = item.getMerged(0);
PdfNumber maxlen = field.getAsNumber(PdfName.MAXLEN);
```

Now you can get the `int` value of `maxlen`.

**Important note:** not every field has a `/MaxLen` value.

Comment: Thanks, a really beautiful answer. Thanks for taking your time, you are awesome!